# How to clear release build for next release in android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

When I run app on device with `react-native run-android` everything is fine.
Once I run app with `react-native run-android --configuration Release` and it was also fine.
But now when I run this same command I can't see changes in my app it's still the same previous version.
I can't find any command that I can use to somehow clean previous release build for new one.
Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Try `cd android && ./gradlew clean`

Comment: Tried that already nothing changes